# use of syncState() in ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class to tie together the functionality of `DrawerLayout` and the framework `ActionBar` to implement the recommended design for navigation drawers.

What Android developer site says is:

> Call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

But I'm not getting what `syncState()` method actually does?

Please explain it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 8):

The `DrawerLayout` indicator is the little icon to the left of the `ActionBar` home icon (see picture)

`ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState` is called properly offset this indicator based on whether or not the `DrawerLayout` is open or closed after the instance state of the `DrawerLayout` has been restored.

[image: DrawerLayout indicator]

Answer (score 6):

Call `syncState()` from your activity's `onPostCreate` to set the state of the indicator based on whether the drawerlayout is in open or closed state once the activity has been restored with `onRestoreInstanceState`.

```
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Display the navigation drawer icon on action bar when there state has changed 
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerListener.syncState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called from your Activity's `onPostCreate` to synchronize the indicator icon with the state of the linked DrawerLayout after `onRestoreInstanceState` has occurred.

for example

```
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.navDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```